# Fallback kernel.img possible in config.txt

Tags: boot, image, config.txt, bootloader

I have a raspberry with a customized OS. The image it should load is described in the config.txt on the boot partition. The image is called zImage and the line in the config.txt is:

`kernel=zImage`

I expect to update it from time to time by updating the whole zImage. Now I am wondering that if I accidentally upload a faulty new `zImage.img` which causes a faulty system start (no start or partial start). Is there a way that I can use a fallback zImage?

So my ideal boot procedure would be:

1. Raspberry checks if a certain file is present on the boot partion (for example `fallback.txt`).
2. If `fallback.txt` is present use the kernel image `fallback.img`
3. If not, use the `zImage.img` and as a first step write the file `fallback.txt`
4. Boot and perform some checks. If everything is ok, delete `fallback.txt`

---

In this configuration I would always have a bootable system, even if I mess up the update of the system. I have been searching if this is possible but I only find procedures to boot through USB.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If there's no

```
kernel=zImage
```

line in `/boot/config.txt` then your system will load `kernel.img`, `kernel7.img` or `kernel7l.img` (depending on the model). So the simple fix is to make

```
kernel=zImage
```

into a comment. You can do that on Windows or with the NOOBS recovery console.

```
#kernel=zImage
```

and it will boot normally (as long as you've got the original kernel and original matching `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` folder that goes with it.

The other quick fix is a second bootable SDCard and a USB reader.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying boot procedure is very difficult on Raspberry Pi because it is a custom solution for Raspberry Pi and deep integrated into the firmware. As far as I know there are parts closed source. You will find a description from the official site at [Raspberry Pi boot modes](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/). Have a look at *Boot flow* there.

Comment: Yes I have checked this. The boot modes only describe possibilities to have external secondary options (USB/ethernet). I am looking for an internal option.